# GNOME Shell crashes repeatedly since Groovy upgrade

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 20.10, mutter

Since I've upgraded to Groovy, my window manager repeatedly crashes. I've found a simple and reliable way to repeat the crash, so here it is :

1. Install the `qemu-system-x86` package
2. Run the following command : `qemu-system-x86_64 -nodefaults -display gtk -device VGA -full-screen`

... and GNOME Shell crashes. You can see the screen blink, that's the crash. All windows that were previously minimised will be raised again. To quit Qemu full screen, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Here's the part of the log that I think is relevant :

```
Dec 03 20:51:26 NovHak-P2 gnome-shell[13840]: JS ERROR: TypeError: actor.__animationInfo is undefined
                                              _sizeChangedWindow@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1385:9
Dec 03 20:51:26 NovHak-P2 gnome-shell[13840]: Error in freeze/thaw accounting
Dec 03 20:51:26 NovHak-P2 gnome-shell[13840]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 5
Dec 03 20:51:26 NovHak-P2 gnome-shell[13840]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba9a140220 ==
Dec 03 20:51:26 NovHak-P2 systemd[11078]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=5/TRAP
Dec 03 20:51:26 NovHak-P2 systemd[11078]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Dec 03 20:51:26 NovHak-P2 systemd[11078]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Dec 03 20:51:26 NovHak-P2 systemd[11078]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
Dec 03 20:51:26 NovHak-P2 systemd[11078]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
```

The first two lines are probably the most informative. I suspect it affects almost all systems, can anyone confirm ?

Besides those crashes, I noticed another annoying thing, when I play a game full screen (namely DCSS, `apt install crawl-tiles`), when I come back to the desktop, the time showed in the upper bar isn't current, it's the time when I started playing. Moving the cursor on the time has it updated to current. I have the feeling it is related to the crashes somehow...

(While playing, the text in the DCSS log has strange artifacts, I suspect it's related too, but maybe that's a DCSS problem after all)

Any suggestions on how to avoid those crashes ?

**EDIT :** While it's an already reported [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1897765), it would still be interesting if someone finds a workaround during the (long ?) time until the fix reaches us. Apart from leaving Gnome 3 that is (which I'm considering more and more btw, with those impractical design choices that are definitely **not** improving, but that's another mutter... eeeh matter).

Comment: Great troubleshooting! This looks like a real, reportable bug. Discussion about it should take place in the bug report, not in AskUbuntu,.

Comment: @user535733 I just discovered it's already been reported ! https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1897765 Unfortunately, the fix takes time to come...

Comment: @KGIII Wait, I posted it as I'm looking for a workaround ! Hence not only a bug report (have a look at my edit)

Comment: I'll retract the flag (I didn't vote). Good choice to edit it to make it clear. Others may also think it's a bug report, but hopefully they'll see this discourse.